# modification of Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continued-fractions

Dedekind defining real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. $x=y$ means $x-y=0$ ie $x_n - y_n \to 0$.  addition and multiplication are defined for each coordinate.

motivated by continued fractions. what if we rescale so that $x=y$ means $n^2(x_n - y_n) \to 0$ does the resulting number system still lead to the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or is there extra "fuzz" around 0?

---

this is motivated by the result that $x$ is irrational iff there are infinitely many fractions such that

$$ \left| x - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| < \frac{1}{q_n^2}$$

Comment: Dedekind cuts and Cauchy sequences are *distinct* definitions of the real numbers. This question is about Cauchy sequences.

Comment: I don't think it's an equivalence relation anymore if you define it like that.

Comment: Dedekind cuts are _not_ equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. See baby Rudin or wikipedia for the definition of a Dedekind cut. You're talking about Cantor's construction of the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard construction of the real numbers via Cauchy sequences can be understood algebraically as follows: Let $R$ be the ring of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers under the operations of component-wise addition and multiplication. Then $\mathfrak m = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in R \mid x_n \to 0\}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, and we define $\mathbb R = R/\mathfrak m$.

Your proposed number system uses instead the ideal $I = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in R \mid n^2 x_n \to 0\}$; it is easy to verify that $I$ is indeed an ideal in $R$, but $I \subsetneq \mathfrak m$, so $R/I$ is not a field. Moreover, $r = (1/n^2)_{n \in \mathbb N} \notin I$, but $r^2 \in I$, so $R/I$ isn't even an integral domain.

So in answer to your question, yes, there is "fuzz" around $0$. I don't know whether or not $\mathfrak m/I$ could be seen as an "interesting" system of infinitesimals, but it definitely behaves differently from, say, the system of infinitesimals in the hyperreals, since you have nilpotents.

Comment: In calculus there is $dt^2 = 0$. Here if $\epsilon=1/n$ the ring should be $\mathbb{R}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^3)$

Comment: yes, well, there is the system of dual numbers, where an infinitesimal is *defined* to have the property that it squares to $0$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number. Your system of numbers is more complicated than that one.

Comment: You can get a non-nilpotent infinitesimal by approximating the sequence $(1/\ln(n+1))$ by rationals.

Comment: I don't know if my model accurately describes continued fractions,  but you certainly answered my question.